# Tabulator.js v5.5 programmatically changed cell value is not shown

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I use Tabulator.js and it is populated from a database by an AJAX call.

I can load any data row into a `form` (in a modal window) for editing but, after submitting the form, I programmatically update the row cells to reflect the changes but it is not happening. The cells appear to have a read only behavior.

I have to reload the page in order to see the changes.

The AJAX response is an object with the data that was sent to the server, so that if the operation was successful, the Tabulator gets updated programmatically without the need to reload the page.

My JS code:

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Tabulator, AjaxModule, FormatModule, ReactiveDataModule, EditModule } from 'tabulator-tables'
    import '../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css'
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       let dataRow = {}
    
       Tabulator.registerModule([AjaxModule, FormatModule, ReactiveDataModule, EditModule])
       var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
          ajaxURL: "/dashboard/getProducts",
          index: "productId",
          reactiveData: true,
          height: "426px",
          placeholder: "No data available",
          autoResize: true,
          columns: [
             { title: "pId", field: "productId", visible: false },
             { title: "Código", field: "productCode", width: 90, bottomCalc: "count" },
             { title: "Descripción", field: "description", width: 450 },
             { title: "Categoría", field: "categoryId" },
             { title: "Precio", field: "price", width: 90 },
             { title: "Marca", field: "brandId" },
             {
                title: "Acciones", formatter: function (cell, formatterParams) {
                   return "<button class='editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success'>Editar</button>&nbsp;<button class='delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger'>Borrar</button>";
                }
             }
          ],
          footerElement:`<div class="row w-100">
                            <div class="col-3"><button id="addProduct" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Agregar producto</button></div>
                            <div class="col-2 pt-1">Productos registrados: <span class="tabulator-counter"></span></div>
                         </div>`,
       })
    
    
       // Submit modal form.
       document.getElementById('acceptBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
          // Get inputs value.
          dataRow.productCode = document.getElementById('productCode').value
          dataRow.description = document.getElementById('description').value
          dataRow.categoryId = document.getElementById('categoryId').value
          dataRow.price = document.getElementById('price').value
          dataRow.brandId = document.getElementById('brandId').value
    
          // Clear inputs
          document.getElementById('productForm').reset()
    
          // Store the product in the DB.
          if (dataRow.productId > 0) {
             // Update the model.
             axios.put('/dashboard/updateProduct', dataRow)
                .then(res => {
                   // Update the grid
                   table.updateData([res.data])
                   //var gridRow = table.getRow(res.data.productId)
                   //gridRow.update(res.data)
                   //table.redraw(true)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                   if (error.response) {
                      Notify('Warning', 'No se pudo actualizar el producto.')
                      console.log('Error:', error.response.data)
                   }
                })
          }
       })
})
```

As you can see in the commented code I have tried using other methods, which do not display any error, but the cells do not get updated with new values from the AJAX response.

I also tried importing and registering different modules (just in case) but to no avail.

Is it possible to change data without having to reload the page to see the changes?